# How to get the data after submit the form based on the form input value using laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

My controller contain single function with multiple API calling when I returned the controller function to my view api data displayed automatically but i need to display the data while submit the form. Please suggest any solution.

My Controller Code

```
public function domaincheck(Request $request)
{
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
<!-- Domain Availability Check -->
    $sld = $request['sld'];
    $tld = $request['tld'];
    $response = file_get_contents('https://resellertest.enom.com/interface.asp?command=check&sld='. $sld .'&tld='. $tld .'&uid=resellid&pw=resellpw&responsetype=xml');  
    $data = simplexml_load_string($response);
    $configdata   = json_encode($data);
    $final_data = json_decode($configdata,true);

 <!--Domain Name Suggestions --> 
  $response1 = file_get_contents('http://resellertest.enom.com/interface.asp?command=GETNAMESUGGESTIONS&uid=resellid&pw=resellpw&SearchTerm='. $sld .'&MaxResults=5&ResponseType=XML');       
    $data1 = simplexml_load_string($response1);
    $configdata1   = json_encode($data1);
    $final_data1 = json_decode($configdata1,true);
}
```

My view Code

```
 <form class="form-horizontal" method="get"> 
  <div class="form-group">
     <div class=" col-lg-2"></div>
     <div class="col-lg-8">
         <div class="input-group m-b">
            <span class="input-group-addon" style="padding-left:10px; background-color: #999;" class='unclickable'>www</span>
            <input type="text" name="sld" class="form-control">
  <span class="input-group-addon">
  <select class="form-control" name="tld" style="width: 100px;">
 <?php $j = 0; ?>
  @foreach($final_data2['tldlist']['tld'] as $value)
  <?php $j++; ?> 
  @endforeach
  @for ($i = 0; $i < $j-1;)
  <option value="{{($final_data2['tldlist']['tld'][$i]['tld'])}}">{{($final_data2['tldlist']['tld'][$i]['tld'])}}</option>
  <?php $i++; ?> 
  @endfor
      </select>  
      </span>
      <span class="input-group-addon">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">Submit</button>  
      </span>
      </div>
                <p class="text-center text-dark customFont" >
                    @foreach($final_data as $key=>$value)
                      @if($key=='DomainName')
                        <b>{{$value}}</b> <b>-</b>
                      @endif 
                      @if($key=='RRPText')
                          <b>{{$value}}</b>
                      @endif
                    @endforeach
                </p>

        {{print_r($final_data1)}}
```

When submit the form (Response) it shows the domain name is available or not available. Response1  is shows the domain name suggestions but it shows the data with out submit the form.Please suggest any solutions

Comment: `my view api data displayed automatically`, u may have keyup event binded to that input, and its firing an ajax call to `domaincheck`

Comment: my input is binded to the response1 and it showed the exact output. But the only problem is to display the response data without form submit. Need to display the data after submit the form.